# How to fetch Contacts from Account Subgrid and set those accounts as a view in another Subgrid on the same form in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to know that

How to fetch Contacts from Account Subgrid and set those accounts as a view in another Subgrid on the same form.

Here is little more explanation , On some Custom Entity form there are two Subgrids (one is Account Subgrid and other is Contact subgrid). When i add Accounts in Account subgrid ,how can i fetch the related Contacts and load those contacts in Contacts Subgrid ?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be directly done with adding the Subgrids of Account and Contact only.If you want to fetch only those contacts that are related with Account, then you will have to make a relationship of custom entity with the Account.If this custom entity has a relationship with the Account, then the contact corresponding to the selected Account will automatically appear.

To make a relationship of custom entity with Account, you can make a new lookup field of Accounts in custom entity and show this lookup field in your form.

By this When you select an Account from lookup field, the contacts related to that Account will automatically appear in the contact subgrid and Account will also display in the Accounts Subgrid.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** supported however you could combine the following two articles.

1. Attach an "onrefresh" event to the grid:
   http://joegilldotcom.blogspot.ie/2011/06/crm-2011-how-to-refresh-form-after.html
2. Filter the Contact sub grid:
   https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/archive/2013/01/24/filter-sub-grid-dynamics-crm-2011-rollup-12-polaris.aspx#.Uf8DYpI3Cdg

You need to think long and hard about whether or not this is of value to your system because both of the above have issues that will make your solution not compatible with certain roll ups.